# Ubuntu python: interface for running multiple script

Tags: python, ubuntu, interface

I've created a few python scripts that I have to run every once in a while, but now I constantly have to type or search the location to the script in order to execute it. I have been looking for simple software to create an app with buttons, but without success.

I have also seen "python?" scripts with an interface where you can select options with arrow keys, but also for this I have not found how it is done.

Is there anyone who knows how I can make one of these that I can open the interface and select the script I want to execute? It would really save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) to create the GUI, and for each button create a function that runs your python script like this:

```
# Create the button
button1 = Button \
    (root, text='Start script1!', command=lambda: script1())

def script1():
    os.system('python ~/path/to/script1.py')
def script2():
    os.system('python ~/path/to/script2.py')
```

Comment: Thanks! I already came across Tkinter in my search, But I often ran into trouble. Thanks to some more youtube and your code I figured out how it works

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) because that framework is the powerful tool for building GUI on python and for running scripts from python code as system processes you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. I think you know how to use Google to find tutorials =) And also you can check the official page with GUI FAQ [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html). Thank you!